# Unwrapping a toroid into 2D space using only point neighbours

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that can unwrap a toroid into a 2D array so I can address the various points using X, Y coordinates and walk over the mesh in a consistent manner.

My problem is that I don't have a whole lot of information to work with. I've got a list of uniquely identified points that make up the toroid, but the integer identifiers are randomized and non-contigous. I've got a list of neighbours associated with each point, but that list is an unordered set.

Somehow, I need to pick a starting point (presumably the point with the lowest identifier integer), then iterate over the entire mesh in such a way that I land up with a 2D array that describes the identifiers of each point as they're laid out across the toroid surface.

How would I best go about solving something like this?

Comment: Is the toroid centred on the origin and aligned with the XY plane, or are you trying to solve for the general case of a toroid situated anywhere in 3D space with any orientation?

Comment: Is it also 2D toroid or is it more dimensional one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2D toroid and you want to put him into 2D array with "neighbours" data, you can do this by this metod.

Toroid is symmetric, therefore you can take any point you want first and put him anywhere into array. I will put it into middle of array, but you can even start in corner, it does not matter.

For 5 x 5 toroid you create 5 x 5 array

```
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - X - X - X
```

You take one from your list and put him into middle

```
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - O - X - X
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - X - X - X
```

Now you want to find these neighbours N identified by neighbour of neighbour F. It is quite easy :

1. Find all neighbours of O
2. Create pairs between them
3. If pair of nodes have two same neighbours, remember them. The one of them is O (the first one) the second is new one F.

The first pair which fulfilled conditions :

```
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - N - F - X
X - X - O - N - X
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - X - X - X
```

You can get 4 pairs (at each direction), but because of symmetric structure, you can just take one and put it to that array

```
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - X - X - X
```

Now you have finally positioned the toroid to something and you can start filling it with values.

Look to these "N" nodes

```
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - N - N - X
X - X - X - X - X
```

Only two exact nodes fulfill these conditions. You already have "O" nodes in array, therefore you know their position. If I mark the important ones (in this step) as 1 and 2, it looks like this

```
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - 1 - 2 - X
X - X - N - N - X
X - X - X - X - X
```

And only two unrevealed nodes fulfill this : "N1 is connected to 1; N2 is connected to 2; N1 and N2 are connected". Therefore you find them and put them in.

```
X - X - X - X - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - X - X - X
```

You can finish whole line with this approach

```
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - O - O - X
```

And now you can do the same to the other direction

```
X - X - O - O - X
O - O - O - O - O
O - O - O - O - O
X - X - O - O - X
X - X - O - O - X
```

And then another one

```
X - X - O - O - X
O - O - O - O - O
O - O - O - O - O
O - O - O - O - O
O - O - O - O - O
```

And last

```
O - O - O - O - O
O - O - O - O - O
O - O - O - O - O
O - O - O - O - O
O - O - O - O - O
```